# unexpected token error importing a vuex store to laravel page

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vuex

New-ish to Vue nd extremely new to Vuex. Im trying to import a store to my main page from which all my components branch out, but I keep getting an "unexpected token {" error in the browser console. I read through the documentation, but I cant find anything that would address this issue. I have tried changing every bit of syntax I can, and it doesnt seem to make a difference. The brackets around store in the import appear to be the problem, but when I remove them, i just get a new "unexpected identifier", or an "unexpected string" error. Am I importing it incorrectly? This format works fine on all my components, just not on this new vue instance.

vuex-test.blade.php

```
@extends('core.core_layouts.core_blank')

@section('browsertitle')
@endsection

@section('top-css')
@endsection

@section('breadcrumb')
@endsection


@section('main')
  <component :is="currentView" v-bind="currentProperties"></component>
@endsection


@section('bottom-js')
<script>

    import { store } from './../stores/store1.js';

    var app = new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        store,
        data: {
        currentView: 'org-list',
        choseOrg: {{ $org }},
    },  // end data
    computed: {
        currentProperties: function() {
            if (this.currentView === 'org-list') { return { } }
            if (this.currentView === 'add-org') { return { parentOrg: '' } }
        }
    },   
    mounted : function() {
    }, // end mounted
    methods: {
    }, // end methods
    components: {
    },
});
</script>
@endsection
```

store1.js

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    safelyStoredNumber: 'ret',
    count: 2,
  },
  mutations: {
    setOrgIdentity(state, orgID) {
    state.OrgID = orgID
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? At the browser? Also, can you show the source for `store1.js`?

Comment: sorry, the question wasn't as complete as it should have been. I have updated it with store1.js nd the complete file where it isnt working.

Comment: And where do you get the error? at the browser?

Comment: yes, at the browser.

Comment: `import` won't work there. Try changing `import { store } from './../stores/store1.js';` to something like `<script src="./../stores/store1.js"></script>` (change the path to what is more appropriate) and in `store1.js` do: `window.store = new Vuex.Store({`.

Comment: that did it! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments:

> Yes, I get the error at the browser.

`import` won't work there. It is meant to run on node.js, during the build phase of a vue-cli-based project.

If you are deploying the code directly to browser, you will need to use code that is supported by the browser. In this case, the solution to import other JavaScript files is standard `<script>` tags.

So, in your code, change:

```
import { store } from './../stores/store1.js';
```

to something like (change the path to what is more appropriate):

```
<script src="./../stores/store1.js"></script>
```

And in **store1.js** (because `export` is too meant for node.js), replace:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
```

With:

```
window.store = new Vuex.Store({
```